# Excel VBA 3704 Error (Can't open connection to AdoDB)

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to process something in my worksheet using adodb.
For some reason I can't open the connection in the first place; the code below gives a 3704 error

I've checked my references, Active X and such is already enabled.

```
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim oCn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim str_provider As String
Dim str_hdr As String
If Application.Version < 12 Then
    str_provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source="
    str_hdr = "Excel 8.0;"
Else
    str_provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="
    str_hdr = "Excel 12.0;"
End If

Dim str_conn
str_conn = str_provider & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Extended Properties='" & str_hdr & "HDR=Yes;'"";"
oCn.Open str_conn
Dim str_query As String
str_query = "select * from " + "final_song" + "where 1=0"
oCn.Execute str_query
```

Comment: What happens when you change `str_hdr = "Excel 12.0;"` to `str_hdr = "Excel 12.0 Xml;`? BTW when is the error happening? For `8.0` or for `12.0`?

Comment: Also change `str_query = "select * from " + "final_song" + "where 1=0"` to this `str_query = "select * from final_song where 1=0"` and see if that makes a difference? There was no space before "Where"

Comment: Is your file in OneDrive?

Comment: @SiddharthRout that gives me a run-time error '02147217805 (80040e73)'. The error's for 12.0

Comment: @SiddharthRout adding a space to "where" does nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: @TimWilliams If you mean the workbook I'm targeting, no its local.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.FullName`.. Is it an xls/xlsm/xlsb file? Try this `"Excel 12.0 Macro;"` for xlsm. You may want to see the different connection strings [HERE](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: Use double quotes `"; Extended Properties=""" & str_hdr & "HDR=Yes;"";"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes in the Extended Properties

```vb
   "; Extended Properties=""" & str_hdr & "HDR=Yes;"";"
```

Assuming you have the data on a sheet named `final_song`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub QuerySQL()

    Const SQL = "SELECT TOP 5 [F1],[F2],[F3] FROM [final_song$]"

    Dim oCn As New ADODB.Connection, oRs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim str_conn As String, str_prop As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, i As Integer, msg As String
    
    ' connection parameters
    If Application.Version < 12 Then
        oCn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        str_prop = "Excel 8.0;"
    Else
        oCn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        str_prop = "Excel 12.0;"
    End If

    ' data source
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    str_conn = "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & "; " & _
               "Extended Properties=""" & str_prop & "HDR=No;"";" ' no header to use F1,F2,F3

    'Debug.Print str_conn
    oCn.ConnectionString = str_conn
    
    ' open connection
    On Error Resume Next
    oCn.Open
    If oCn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        msg = oCn.ConnectionString & vbCrLf
        For i = 1 To oCn.Errors.Count
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & oCn.Errors.Item(i-1).Description
        Next
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Debug.Print Join(Split(oCn.ConnectionString, ";"), vbCrLf)
    
    ' execute
    Set oRs = oCn.Execute(SQL)
    MsgBox oRs.GetString, vbInformation

End Sub
```